Error while building "hello" cordova project
I am starting with cordova and I was trying to build the sample hello application.
Here the command I used:
cordova create hello
cd hello
cordova platform add android ios
cordova build android

the first three commands were ok, last command give this:
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/domenicogagliano/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/domenicogagliano/Library/Android/sdk

Welcome to Gradle 8.7!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Compiling and testing with Java 22
 - Cacheable Groovy script compilation
 - New methods in lazy collection properties

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
...............10%................20%................30%................40%...............50%................60%................70%................80%...............90%................100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.6!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Added support for Java 19.
 - Introduced `--rerun` flag for individual task rerun.
 - Improved dependency block for test suites to be strongly typed.
 - Added a pluggable system for Java toolchains provisioning.

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/domenicogagliano/cordova_test/hello/platforms/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/domenicogagliano/.gradle/caches/7.6/scripts/dqjrgsw17c62wbpoagod92e1e).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/domenicogagliano/cordova_test/hello/platforms/android/gradlew -b /Users/domenicogagliano/cordova_test/hello/platforms/android/build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

It seems that it first builds with gradle 8.7.0 which is the version I have installed, then it downloads 7.6
What could be the problem there?
Thanks for any reply!
